# 500 Internal Server Error with increased usage

Tags: php

As I have allowed more than 3 or 4 users logged into my site, It has now become preposterously slow and often giving 500 internal server error.

It is an SQL database using wordpress that I moved from MAMP of my laptop to the server online. This procedure caused a few errors with URL's etc that I had to correct in the database with find and replace.

Could there be something I missed causing this? What am I looking for?

Comment: IMO, NEVER do a database-wide find and replace!
Are you sure that you have configured your server to use correct database settings and database engines ?

Comment: No idea.... Can you advise me here

Comment: is there some restriction on the data that your server allows you to store ? i have frequently face 500 error when my log files increase a certain limit.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to find the PHP error log and check for errors. Also check the MySQL log file for errors. Any fatal error should be logged somewhere and the log message is your system's way of telling you what went wrong.